# Rename pandas dataframe column name based on a list

Tags: pandas, rename

i have multiple dataframes with many columns, each df have different column names and i want to standardize the name to be able o merge them properly

i want to be able to rename the column to a standard name

what i did is i created a list of possible column name options and i looped through the columns in the df if the name is in this list, rename to standard name

```
res_list=['SEDP', 'SFXE', 'RPCHM', 'AT90']  # standard name is RLA5
cols = df_test.columns

    for col in cols:
        if df_test[col].isin(res_list):
            df_test.rename({col:'RLA5'}, axis=1, inplace =True)
        else:
            pass
```

but this doesn't work and give the error below

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Comment: I recommend printing `df_test[col].isin(res_list)` to see what it returns. that should make things pretty clear

Comment: thanks, i tried col in res_list: and it worked but the solution below is much better as it is much shorter and easier to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct a mapping dictionary to [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the columns if present

```
mapper = dict.fromkeys(['SEDP', 'SFXE', 'RPCHM', 'AT90'], 'RLA5')
df_test.rename(columns=mapper, inplace=True)
```